# QWebView not displaying simple HTML

Tags: qt

My Qt code is pretty simple:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWebView>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QWebView* view = new QWebView;
  view->setUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\website.html"));
  view->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

However, this just displays a blank page when the application starts up.  Any ideas?  I'm trying to follow simple tutorials and have searched.  I even tried loading Google and that failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to set the proxy settings.  My code looks like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QNetworkProxy>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QNetworkProxy proxy;
  proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
  proxy.setHostName(QString("PROXY_IP_ADDRESS"));
  proxy.setPort(PROXY_PORT);
  QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);

  QWebView view;
  view.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
  view.showFullScreen();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: You may also need to use proxy.setUser and proxy.setPassword depending on your system configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following setting:

```
view.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls,true);
```